# easier way to format lines of code in Java to make your job easier?

Tags: java

I am currently making an application that uses an api and it prints out information about that thing. So basically it gets the api and If i do `System.out.println(result.getPlayer().get("displayname"));` it will return the display name of the player that I am searching for. I was wondering if there was a way to make `result.getPlayer().get("displayname")` a variable  because I have hundreds of statistics that I need to gather. so is it possible to have that line of code called `displayname`? Sorry if you don't understand.

Comment: Is it possible to hold a value in a variable? Of course, that's literally the point of variables.

Comment: may you show me how? because I can't figure it out

Comment: Are you asking how to write instance variables within a class?

Comment: use a getter `result.getPlayer().getDisplayName()`

Comment: so my code returns like over 1000 different json values, in my program I am going to be using lots of them. Instead of me doing `result.getPlayer().get("displayname");` is there a way that I can have that set to a variable that I can set to be printed out? and what kind of variable would it be?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you make a special statistics/logging class that has static methods specifically for this. For example with your case, the following class can be used both to get the name and to print it. Of course you can combine them into a single method if you want just one functionality.

```
public class StatsLog {
    public static String getPlayerDisplayName(final Result result) {
        return (result == null)
            ? null
            : result.getPlayer().get("displayname");
    }

    public static void printPlayerDisplayName(final Result result) {
        final String displayName = getPlayerDisplayName(result);
        if (displayName != null) {
            System.out.println(displayName);
        }
    }
}
```

And when you call it:

```
StatsLog.printPlayerDisplayName(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a getter like @Andrew Tobilko said. like this:

```
public String getDisplayName(){
      return (result != null)? result.getPlayer().get("displayname") : "";
}
```

However, it depends on what is the "result" and the design of your class. And make sure to check for Null.

Comment: how can I get `result ` if it is a different class?